# Finding file based on user input?

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory, user-input, web-folders

I printed files using os.listdir() and found the files inside the folder i am looking for. I'm now looking for user input to know which files to look in. The files are in years and month and I'm not sure how?

[Picture of my code now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jchPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a year and month as input from the user?
In that case you could parse the input string, then use some kind of regex matching to find the corresponding file.

Comment: Im first asking for year, if the year is in the folder im asking for the month. If not im telling the user the year/month is not avalible. Im new to python so i dont know how

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could try using this in that case:

```
year = input("Enter year :")
month = input("Enter day :")
date = year + month
found = False
for file_name in a:
    if date in file_name:
        print("File found!")
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: When i put the code in, it outputs "File not found" even if i put in the correct year and month

Comment: could you go with endswith( date + ".csv") since all the files ends with .csv and it is following the date?

Comment: I have come to the point where i find the file but im using the command file[0]. then im finding fil nr. 1 but not nr. 2 if i want nr.2. how can i fix that?